# how to tell if my stdin is coming from stdout or stderr of the piped-in process

Tags: linux, bash

How to tell from Linux `process2` whether I am given standard output or error from the previous process.  Is it possible, to tell inside process2, whether particular line comes from stderr or stout

```
bash>process1 2>&1 | process2
```

So I guess by John's answer, it is "no".  Then I am guessing, one way to handle this, is to inject specific prefixes for each line inside process1:

```
1: <line>
```

for stdout

```
2: <line>
```

for stderr

then I can inspect them in process2.  Is this the normal thing to do?

Comment: In what way should this matter?

Comment: well, suppose I want to process the stream in process2, and then direct it back to output, if it came from output, and to error, if it came from error

Comment: and if I try to run two process2, one for each stream, then I have difficulty synchronizing their outputs, you see, because typically, error has much less stuff, than standard output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible.  You can differentiate stdin from a terminal by `isatty()` but not what sort of stream the input came from in the way you want.